# Create 90 identical site collections

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have inherited a project and design. We have 90 districts in use each district will have their own site collection. All the artifacts within the site collection will be same (meant lists, document libs, content types...).

Question: How can I create 90 site collections based on an individual site collection? I will very much appreciate your feedback.

Comment: save one as the template and create the other site collections based on that template?

Answer (score 0):

Get the master site exactly as you want it with all lists, document libraries and the corresponding views set and any other custom features you want. I recommend using pages and embedding webpart views for a clean style. Then, go into the Site Settings (little gear upper left hand corner) and under the Site Actions area click "Save Site as Template". Name the template something interesting that you like to differentiate it. This same approach can be used to save any other object within SP like a list or document library, it will even allow you to save the items within the list/library.

Once you have create the site template you can go about using your normal routine to create a new site and instead of picking an OOB template you can pick your template by name. By default everything will be named exactly as you have the master.

So if you call it "District 1" then all of your groups will be called "District 1 - Members, Owners, Visitors" -- so, keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

I have been working with this same question...

There seem to be a number of ways to get the job done all with advantages and disadvantages.  I am at a loss as to what is considered 'best practice' but here is where I ended up :

- The first option that I considered (as has been suggested) was to create a site template using the SharePoint UI tools 
  (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj938033(v=office.15).aspx )

I decided not to use this as I found it too hard to maintain.  If you want to go this way, here is an excellent article that might help.  (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sambetts/archive/2013/10/17/creating-a-clean-visual-studio-solution-from-a-sharepoint-2013-site-template.aspx)

- The second option that I looked at is to use a 'web template'.  This involves creating a visual studio solution with two features to deploy your new template.  You 'steal' the base files for your web template from the existing site type that you want to customise such as a team site.  You can then modify the onet.xml to add whatever features and artifacts you wish to deploy when a new site is created.  This article is for SharePoint 2010 but I think it has the right steps. (http://www.sharepointchick.com/archive/2011/02/10/using-web-templates-to-create-site-collections.aspx)

Once you have chosen how to deploy the site collection / site, you need to add the artifacts to it (lists, libraries, pages etc.).

I deploy all of my customisations using features.  I started out working with declarative deployment (ie. using elements.xml files) to define fields, lists, content types, list definitions, views etc.

I came across a number of situations where I had issues upgrading these items after they had been initially deployed.

For this reason I am working to deploy all my customisations to the team site using code that runs in a feature receiver. Thanks go to the author of the following article (http://geekswithblogs.net/djacobus/archive/2013/10/15/154360.aspx).

If you choose to go this way, I can provide the modified code that I am using for my provisioning.  This method does require being comfortable with Visual Studio, debugging and the SSOM.

Hope this helps !